# Как программно поставить метку на яндекс-карту, которую можно передвинуть? как отследить ее координаты?

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты

По документации яндекс.карт создал карту на которую поставил метку.
Как мне зафиксировать карту, чтобы она не масштабировалась скролу?
нашел метод `behavior.ScrollZoom` у которого есть метод `disable` но как его применить не понял.

в документации был пример  `.disable(['drag', 'rightMouseButtonMagnifier'])`, но что то он совсем отличается от `behavior.ScrollZoom`
А после того как зафиксирую карту нужно дать возможность передвигать метку.

Как получить координаты метки после завершения передвижения? (если можно просто вывести в консоль)

```js
ymaps.ready(init);

function init() {
  var myMap = new ymaps.Map("map", {
    center: [55.76, 37.64],
    zoom: 14
  });
  myMap.behaviors.disable(['scroll', 'zoom']);
  var myPlacemark = new ymaps.Placemark([55.76, 37.64], {
    hintContent: 'Содержимое всплывающей подсказки',
    balloonContent: 'Содержимое балуна'
  });

  myMap.geoObjects.add(myPlacemark);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/2.1/?lang=ru_RU"></script>
<div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 250px"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выключить скроллзум можно так: https://jsfiddle.net/o9s2gb5r/

```
myMap.behaviors.disable(['scrollZoom']);
```

А так подписаться на окончание драга и вернуть координаты: https://jsfiddle.net/sxzn09dp/

```
myPlacemark.events.add('dragend', function () {
            console.log(myPlacemark.geometry.getCoordinates());
        });
```